# In C++, reference as class member shall be const or non-const

Tags: c++, reference, constants, const-cast

Consider the following minimal example.

```
#include <vector>

class Data
{
    std::vector<int>& v;
public:
    Data(std::vector<int>& _v) : v(_v) {}
    Data(const std::vector<int>& _v) : v(_v) {} // error!
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    const std::vector<int> c_v;
    Data d(v);
    Data const_d(c_v);

    return 0;
}
```

This does not compile. The whole output from `g++ -Wall` below.

```
const.cpp: In constructor ‘Data::Data(const std::vector<int>&)’:
const.cpp:8:41: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::vector<int>&’ from expression of type ‘const std::vector<int>’
```

The reason is clear to me: The const keyword is upset about my cast in line 8. The issue: I really sometimes need the Data class with `std::vector`, but sometimes with `const std::vector`. Like having two classes: One for reading into `Data`, and one for reading from `Data`. However, I do not like to write two Data classes with almost redundant functions. My questions:

- Can you give a nice solution to how I can achieve what I try to do in `main()`? C++11 solutions are pretty welcome, too :)
- Is this the reason for `iterator` and `const_iterator`?

Comment: Note: I am currently thinking about making `std::vector<int>` a template, but is this the best solution? :)

Comment: Could you include compilation error as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const`-ness of data members needs to be known at compile time. If you "sometimes" need a reference to a `const` vector and sometimes non-`const`, you should create a class hierarchy with the base abstract class containing the common functionality, and inherit it in two `Data` classes: `Data` and `ConstData`. The `Data` would contain a non-`const` vector, and `ConstData` would contain a `const` vector. This way you would not duplicate any logic, while two separate classes would contain two references of different `const`-ness.

Here is an example:

```
class AbstractData {
public:
    // Common functions use vect() and const_vect()
    void common_function1();
    void common_function2();
protected:
    virtual vector<int>& vect() const = 0;
    virtual const vector<int>& const_vect() const = 0;
};

class Data : public AbstractData {
    vector<int>& v;
public:
    Data(vector<int>& _v) : v(_v) {}
protected:
    vector<int>& vect() const {
        return v;
    }
    const vector<int>& const_vect() const {
        return v;
    }
};

class ConstData : public AbstractData {
    const vector<int>& v;
    vector<int> temp;
public:
    ConstData(const vector<int>& _v) : v(_v) {}
protected:
    vector<int>& vect() const {
        return temp; // You can choose to throw an exception instead
    }
    const vector<int>& const_vect() const {
        return v;
    }
};
```

Note that this class hierarchy may need a destructor and various copy constructors, depending on the usage.

Comment: Nice reasoning! So my idea with using template wasn't so bad? Probably a good exercise to use CRTP here instead of virtual functions? :)

Comment: @Johannes One problem with a template-based solution is that you wouldn't be able to easily differentiate between the const type `T` vs. the non-const one. If some functions of your template would need to access the vector in a non-const way, the entire template would fail to compile. A template-based solution would inherit a "mutable" data template class from the "immutable" data template class, and add mutating functions to it.

Comment: not 100 percent sure if I got that. If I have multiple objets to store, I'd use a typelist or something similar. Shouldn't this set the type at compile time?

Comment: @Johannes Yes, that will set the type at compile time. The issue is, if the type happens to be `const`, and some of your template's methods require non-const access, these methods will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got was along the lines of:

```
foo.cpp: In constructor ‘Data::Data(const std::vector<int>&)’:
foo.cpp:8:44: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::vector<int>&’ from expression of type ‘const std::vector<int>’
```

...because you are trying to create a non-const reference to data that you (`Data`) promised your caller would be treated as `const`.

Here is a solution which declares a `const` reference as `Data`'s member:

```
#include <vector>

class Data
{
    const std::vector<int> &v;
public:
    Data(std::vector<int>& _v) : v(_v) {}
    Data(const std::vector<int>& _v) : v(_v) {} // error!
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<int> c_v;
    Data d(v);
    Data const_d(c_v);

    return 0;
}
```

Another option is to use a non-reference member instead:

```
#include <vector>

class Data
{
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    Data(std::vector<int>& _v) : v(_v) {}
    Data(const std::vector<int>& _v) : v(_v) {} // error!
};
```

Comment: Please note: I changed c_v to a *const* vector in main(). Though this works for your code I think.

Comment: Your code works, but I need the `Data` class to have `v` const sometimes. So it's no solution :(

Comment: In that case, you should refer to @dasblinkenlight's answer.